# Android Studio Google AdMob apk chrashing error

Tags: java, android, button, admob

Hy!
I writed the codes from AdMob into the source code, but now when I want to start my app, it crashing.
I can't solve this, and the Studio isn't say any problems, just crashing the app on the mobile.
Where is the problem, I can't find it, can you please help me?
Here is my code(ID-s are hided):

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.brtrsoundboard">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application> 

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/grey">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/ad_view2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="ID"/>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonrectangle"
                android:onClick="playButton1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="A k*rva anyádat Brétúró"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonrectangle"
                android:onClick="playButton2"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Anyád biztos büszke rád"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonrectangle"
                android:onClick="playButton3"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Arcade, Arcade a srác neve"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonrectangle"
                android:onClick="playButton4"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="B*asszak rá arra a kugli kopasz fejedre"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonrectangle"
                android:onClick="playButton5"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Fú de értelmes gyerek vagy"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonrectangle"
                android:onClick="playButton6"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Grafikust kifizetted már?"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonrectangle"
                android:onClick="playButton7"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hete Brétúró"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonrectangle"
                android:onClick="playButton8"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Mosógépet kifizetted?"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonrectangle"
                android:onClick="playButton9"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Nem hallak, vedd ki a f*szt a szádból"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonrectangle"
                android:onClick="playButton10"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Te kopasz köcsög"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/ad_view1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="ID" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
    package com.example.brtrsoundboard;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;

import static com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer button1,button2,button3,button4,button5,button6,button7,button8,button9,button10;
    AdView adView1,adView2;
    InterstitialAd interstitialAd;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        adView1=findViewById(R.id.ad_view1);
        adView2=findViewById(R.id.ad_view2);

        MobileAds.initialize(this,"ID");


        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView1.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView2.loadAd(adRequest);

        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ID");
        interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());





       button1=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.a_kurva_anyadat_breturo);
       button2=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.anyad_bizrtos_buszke_rad);
       button3=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.arked_a_srac_neve);
       button4=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.basszak_ra_arra);
       button5=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.fu_de_ertelmes_gyermek_vagy);
       button6=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.grafikust_kifizetted_mar);
       button7=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.hade_breturo);
       button8=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.mosogepet_kifizetted);
       button9=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.nem_hallak);
       button10=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.te_kopasz_kocsog);
    }
    public void playButton1(View view){
        button1.start();
    }
    public void playButton2(View view){
        button2.start();
    }
    public void playButton3(View view){
        button3.start();
    }
    public void playButton4(View view){
        button4.start();
    }
    public void playButton5(View view){
        button5.start();
    }
    public void playButton6(View view){
        button6.start();
    }
    public void playButton7(View view){
        button7.start();
    }
    public void playButton8(View view){
        button8.start();
    }
    public void playButton9(View view){
        button9.start();
    }
    public void playButton10(View view){
        button10.start();
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
    2020-05-18 17:53:27.782 18492-18492/? I/.brtrsoundboar: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2020-05-18 17:53:27.819 18492-18492/? I/.brtrsoundboar: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
2020-05-18 17:53:27.838 18492-18492/? W/.brtrsoundboar: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-05-18 17:53:28.382 18492-18492/com.example.brtrsoundboard I/.brtrsoundboar: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2020-05-18 17:53:29.174 18492-18492/com.example.brtrsoundboard D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-05-18 17:53:29.175 18492-18492/com.example.brtrsoundboard D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-05-18 17:53:29.184 18492-18492/com.example.brtrsoundboard D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-05-18 17:53:29.188 18492-18492/com.example.brtrsoundboard E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.brtrsoundboard, PID: 18492
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

    ******************************************************************************
    * The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
    * should follow the instructions here:                                       *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
    * to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
    * Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
    ******************************************************************************


        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7090)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6630)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6547)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:231)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1887)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7478)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

    ******************************************************************************
    * The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
    * should follow the instructions here:                                       *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
    * to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
    * Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
    ******************************************************************************


        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzyc.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.1.0:33)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.1.0:3)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7085)
            ... 10 more
2020-05-18 17:53:29.989 18492-18492/com.example.brtrsoundboard I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18492 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat?

Comment: Yes, I edit the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your app ID inside the AndroidManifest like this:

```xml
<manifest>
    <application>
        <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

See: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#update_your_androidmanifestxml

Answer (score 1):

You should add below in manifest

```
         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
            android:value="true" />
```

Add your ***AdMob App ID*** to your app's `AndroidManifest.xml` file by adding a  tag with name **`com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID`**

```
<manifest>
    <application>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

For more information, Read official guideline about [**`Import the Mobile Ads SDK`**](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start).